# Who has an Easy Apache 4 Experimental Repo with PHP 7.2 Memcached working?

Tags: php, memcached, cpanel, centos7

I followed the instructions on the bottom of this page: https://engintron.com/docs/#/pages/Install-Memcached-in-cPanel-(EasyApache-4-only)#updatedonjune29th2018

It only includes Memcached up to PHP 7.1.

Is there someone out there that has successfully added Memcached 7.2 to cPanel Easy Apache 4?

I looked into PECL & Docker and I think I'm way over my head.

Comment: Update: I followed the directions on the link above and got the following errors.

Comment: WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update

Comment: Warning: popen() has been disabled for security reasons in /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear/OS/Guess.php on line 241

Comment: Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear/OS/Guess.php on line 242

Comment: Warning: pclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear/OS/Guess.php on line 251
pecl/memcached can optionally use PHP extension "igbinary" (version >= 2.0)
pecl/memcached can optionally use PHP extension "msgpack" (version >= 2.0)
15 source files, building
running: phpize

Comment: Warning: popen() has been disabled for security reasons in /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear/PEAR/Builder.php on line 465
ERROR: failed to run `phpize'